# Safari show Pop-Up on window.open

Tags: javascript, safari, popup, apex

hope someone can help me with this. The code snippet works fine. The only thing is on an iPad/Safari this code opening new tab runs into the pop-up blocker. If we disable the pop-up blocker (which would be OK) there is still a message showing up "This site is attempting to open a pop-up window" with the buttons "Block" and "Allow" - screenshot attached. Clicking "Allow" opens the new tab.

[PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPo9.jpg)

**How to avoid the pop-up blocker and this message?**

**Try 1 (popup shows up):**

```html
var popUp = window.open(SurveyLinkval);
try {
 popUp.focus();   
}catch (e) {
 alert("Pop-up Blocker is enabled! Please disable your pop-up blocker.");
}
```

**Try 2 (popup shows up):**

```html
$('#newTabLink').attr('href', SurveyLinkval);
$('#newTabLink')[0].click();
```

**Below HTML code does work:**

```
<a id="newTabLink" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/" style="display:block;">Open in New Tab Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to "fix" in the browsers. Some browsers, like Safari don't allow open popups if the user doesn't do any action.

Each action or `Event` can be **"Trusted"** or not. The event will be trusted if the user makes any interaction to fire the event in another case the context will be **Untrusted**.

In both cases, you use javascript without user interaction. So, to prevent unexpected windows, Safari will block the popups.

If you put your code in a function and you fire it with `onClick`, when the **user** makes the click (user interaction) the context of the event will be trusted and the window.open will be performed without any inconvenient.

For example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <span onclick="onAnyTextClick()">anyText</span>
        <script>
            function onAnyTextClick() {
                var popUp = window.open("https://www.google.com");
                try {
                    popUp.focus();
                }catch (e) {
                    alert("Pop-up Blocker is enabled! Please disable your pop-up blocker.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good to know:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I think we know how to proceed. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could help,
To open an URL with Safari (version 16.0), which did not consider it was a popup, with the following code:

```
// Set my target URL
var newUrl = "http://www.myurl.com";
// Create an <a> tag with JQuery
var newa = $('<a id="newiddocdl" href="' + newUrl + '" target="_blank"></a>');
// Append this tag in the body part (it will remain invisible)
$('body').append( newa );
// Wait a little for the DOM to record this new tag. 50ms is arbitrary
setTimeout( function()
{
    // Simulate a user click
    $('#newiddocdl')[0].click();
    // The new window, or tab, will open, free the new <a> tag from body
    $('#newiddocdl').remove();
}, 50 );
```